# Extremely slow loading time for firebase retrieval ngFor

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

As shown below is my typescript file

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseService:     FirebaseServiceProvider) {
this.shoppingItems = this.firebaseService.getShopCategories().valueChanges();
}
```

and my html file

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems | async">
<img [src]="item.testee"/>
<div class="card-title" [innerHTML]="item.jobCat"></div>
<div class="card-subtitle"[innerHTML]="item.testing"></div>
</ion-card>
```

Inside the ShopCategories code:

```
getShopCategories(){
return this.afd.list('/shopCategories/');   
}
```

the lag takes around 30 seconds before my ngFor is loaded up. Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Comment: also post the code inside your service `.getShopCategories()`

Comment: have done so, let me know if u can help

Comment: this looks ok to me, check your network tab in developer tools. see anything unusual happens.

Comment: For some reason it's working fine now after the lag happened for months. What i did was just exporting out the apk file to my android phone. Could have done updates to ionic etc to the latest version im not sure but regardless, the issue doesnt exist anymore!

Comment: sorry an update: it's not working. apparently the issue comes after facebook login.